# Looking for expression similar to «sideline detail»

Tags: meaning, expressions

I'm not sure I can use the phrase «sideline detail». By it, I mean a detail that may seem/is secondary.

Is there an expression for this idea?

Comment: At this moment I can suggest two options : peripheral, irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends on the degree to which this particular detail is secondary. To me, the phrase you gave sounds strange. I have some suggestions:

- An incidental detail
- A minor detail
- An impertinent detail
- An irrelevant detail
- A secondary detail
- A complementary detail
- An added detail
- An additional detail
- A supplementary detail
- Another detail
- A further detail
- An unimportant detail
- A superfluous detail
- A nonessential or unessential detail

Comment: No problem, it was a good exercise!